# Seeds database every time I run rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I know to seed the database, I run rake db:seed and everything. I have my seeds.rb file all set up:

```
users = [{:name => 'User1 Lastname', :email => 'user1@example.com', :password => 'password'},
         {:name => 'User2', :email => 'user2@example.com', :password => 'password'},
         {:name => 'User3', :email => 'user3@example.com', :password => 'password'},
         {:name => 'User4', :email => 'user4@example.com', :password => 'password'},
         {:name => 'User5', :email => 'user5@example.com', :password => 'password'},
         {:name => 'User6', :email => 'user6@example.com', :password => 'password'},
         {:name => 'User7', :email => 'user7@example.com', :password => 'password'},
         {:name => 'User8', :email => 'user8@example.com', :password => 'password'},
         {:name => 'User9', :email => 'user9@example.com', :password => 'password'},
         {:name => 'User10', :email => 'user10@example.com', :password => 'password'},
         {:name => 'User11', :email => 'user11@example.com', :password => 'password'},
         {:name => 'User12', :email => 'user12@example.com', :password => 'password'},
         {:name => 'User13', :email => 'user13@example.com', :password => 'password'},
         {:name => 'User14', :email => 'user14@example.com', :password => 'password'},
         {:name => 'User15', :email => 'user15@example.com', :password => 'password'},
         {:name => 'User16', :email => 'user16@example.com', :password => 'password'},
         {:name => 'User17', :email => 'user17@example.com', :password => 'password'},
         {:name => 'User18', :email => 'user18@example.com', :password => 'password'},
         {:name => 'User19', :email => 'user19@example.com', :password => 'password'},
         {:name => 'User20', :email => 'user20@example.com', :password => 'password'},
     ]

users.each do |user|
  User.create(user)
end
```

But now whenever I run `rails server` it seeds them all again! I thought that was only supposed to happen when I run `rake db:seed`

```
~$ rails server
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.2.14 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Connecting to database specified by database.yml
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  User Exists (21.5ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE LOWER("users"."email") = LOWER('user1@example.com') LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  User Exists (1.4ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE LOWER("users"."email") = LOWER('user2@example.com') LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  User Exists (1.3ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE LOWER("users"."email") = LOWER('user3@example.com') LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
```

etc etc for 20 users then launches it:

```
[2013-11-07 00:59:14] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2013-11-07 00:59:14] INFO  ruby 1.9.3 (2013-06-27) [i686-linux]
[2013-11-07 00:59:14] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=1742 port=3000
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!! Thank you

Comment: I don't get the downvote and the close vote, since it is clear what is being asked. Do you happen to have a custom file in config/initializers/ which may lead to this behavior?

Comment: Insert a `raise` in your `seeds.rb`, the stack trace should point you in the right direction.

Comment: It is not supposed to run seed task, so that's probably something you introduced. Did you add custom initializers or invoked seed programmaticaly ? +1 for inserting a raise, may help.

Comment: It turned out to be something in my initializers. Another teammate copied it over for testing and forgot to take it out. Thank you everyone!

Comment: Could you please pull down your question or rather answer it for yourself. There are tons of folks out here willing to answer the unanswered-ones. And this question certainly wastes their time. Well, it certainly did waste mine.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out to be something in my initializers. Another teammate copied it over for testing and forgot to take it out. Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 0):

I make seed as follow:

```
users = []
20.times do |n|
  user << {:name => "Oleg#{n} Sobchuk",
           :email => "user#{n}@example.com",
           :password => 'password'}
end

users.each do |user|
  User.find_or_create_by_name_and_email_and_password(user[:name],
                                                     user[:email],
                                                     user[:password])
end
```

as for me, it is follow DRY and clearer!